# Spring external config

Tags: java, spring

I am new to spring and in my project I use properties file to read ip config like this.

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:ipaddress.properties")
```

And in my properties file

```
ip=http://192.168.1.199:8888
```

The properties file exists in my project(com.test....) but I would like to remove from my project and read the ip address from somewhere else from jboss config or something. It would be appreciated if someone could guide me on this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using maven? If yes, this maybe it would be good idea to put this into Maven profile, like this:

pom.xml

```
...
<profiles>
  <profile>
      <id>dev</id>
      <properties>
          <ip.address>http://192.168.1.199:8888</ip.address>
      </properties>
  </profile>
  <profile>
      <id>test</id>
      <properties>
          <ip.address>http://10.34.65.1:8888</ip.address>
      </properties>
  </profile>
<profiles>
...
<properties>
    <resource.directory>src/main/resources</resource.directory>
</properties>
...
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>${resource.directory}</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
...
```

ipaddress.properties:

```
ip=${ip.address}
```

Maven will then put ip address of active profile while build into ipaddress.properties - so you can change ips without code or properties change - only by setting active profile.

Answer (score 1):

you can try to use something like that:

```
@PropertySources({
    @PropertySource("classpath:application.properties"),
    @PropertySource(value = "file:config/application.properties", ignoreResourceNotFound = true)
```

})

`file:config/application.properties` should be location of external application.properties file.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Spring Boot Probably this [Externalized Configuration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) would give you and idea how to do it.

In my case, my project was deployed in a Centos 7 server. I've done it this way:

```
java -jar <spring-application>.jar --spring.config.location=file:/path-to-property-file/application.properties
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks much for help. I finally got the answer using JNDI in my standalone which is as below :

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:naming:1.2">
    <bindings>
        <simple name="java:/ip" value=" http://123.456.789.123:4567"/>
    </bindings>
</subsystem>
```

And I removed this in code

```
@PropertySource("classpath:ipaddress.properties")
```